# => ERROR [5/5] RUN npm install or yarn in Dockerfile

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm, yarn-v2

I am trying to Dockerise a React app, but when it reaches  the command to install `npm` it throws an error.

My Dockerfile contains:

```sh
# pull official base image
FROM node:12.6.0-alpine


# set working directory
RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

RUN yarn

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The error is this when it reaches the command to run `npm install` or `yarn`:

```
[5/5] RUN yarn:                                                                                                                             
#9 0.725 yarn install v1.16.0                                                                                                                  
#9 0.789 info No lockfile found.                                                                                                               
#9 0.801 warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.   
#9 0.809 [1/4] Resolving packages...
#9 1.507 warning axios@0.19.2: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
#9 8.363 warning formik > create-react-context > fbjs > core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
#9 40.35 error Couldn't find the binary git
#9 40.35 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn]: exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

> #9 40.35 error Couldn't find the binary git

Solution: install git in your docker image.

Answer (score 2):

Install git in your image like this

```
FROM node:12.6.0-alpine
RUN apk update && apk add git

# set working directory
RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

RUN yarn

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. 
also, I am currently working on React(UI) and I need to see the changes on the dom every time I change the code on my VS editor, is there any way to keep the container listening to the changes and update the image instantly?. 
 - not sure but maybe volume or something like that 
here is my docker file
FROM node:12.6.0-alpine
RUN apk update && apk add git

# set working directory
RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

RUN yarn

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]

Answer (score -1):

the package was not installing due to admin authorization issues so I use force command to install and it worked

```
RUN npm install --force
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).